# Python on website to connect to phone connected to computer

Tags: javascript, android, python, django

I know the title is a bit off, but what I'm asking is if it is possible to have a python script on my website that can detect if my Android phone is connected to the computer Im using to view the page. I don't know if this is possible since I think python is server-side, but maybe this is possible to do with JavaScript? I'm fairly new to programming so I may not be as smart as you guys out there but if someone could just lead me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Comment: Honestly, I hope random webpages *can't* tell what devices are connected to your computer. Privacy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is not TOTALLY ABSOLUTELY impossible, but you may need some help from the computer you connect the device to, from the browser you're visiting your site with or from the device itself. Some possible options:

- have a program running on your computer which checks if the device is connected and pinging a certain URL on your website if it is.
- write a browser plugin which checks if the device is connected and exposing the information via some JS API - the JS code on your site will be able to use it.
- have a program running on your device which pings your site each time the device is connected to a computer.

Admittedly, all the solutions are from the "tricky" category :)

Comment: These are all great solutions, thanks for the input I think I will look into creating a browser plugin for it.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for isn't possible and should not be possible for security concerns.  Do you want someone knowing what devices you have connected to your computer?  You're essentially wanting a device sniffer but a website would not be capable of accessing the client's machine in this manner to access the desired information.

Comment: I wanted it on a personal site that only I would use, and I guess I thought it would have to be granted permission by the phone owner. But I guess you're right I really didn't think about that, and at the end of the day I'd rather be safe than sorry, thanks for bringing this to my attention.